# PowerShell Command Highlighting

Tags: powershell

When I type a message into powershell such as `git commit -m 'Commit msg'` I'm unable to see the `-m` due to syntax highlighting.
Is there a way to disable this feature or change the colors it is using?

Everything I can find online regarding syntax highlighting in powershell seems to be about programming scripts and is unrelated.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can edit/customize this feature using the following commandlet:

`Set-PSReadlineOption`

In the example you posted, the parameter `-m` is invisible due to your dark console background color, so you would want to change the **parameter** foreground color like in the following example:

`Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Parameter -ForegroundColor Blue`

Obviously you can replace "Blue" in the above command with your desired color.  I have included the list of colors which can be used for console enumeration as well as the different tokens which can be modified below.

**List of Console Enumeration Colors**

```
Black   
Blue    
Cyan    
DarkBlue    
DarkCyan    
DarkGray    
DarkGreen   
DarkMagenta
DarkRed 
DarkYellow  
Gray    
Green   
Magenta 
Red 
White   
Yellow
```

**List of tokens** (found by using the `Get-PSReadlineOption` commandlet)

```
DefaultTokenForegroundColor            : DarkYellow
CommentForegroundColor                 : Green
KeywordForegroundColor                 : Green
StringForegroundColor                  : DarkCyan
OperatorForegroundColor                : DarkGray
VariableForegroundColor                : Green
CommandForegroundColor                 : Yellow
ParameterForegroundColor               : DarkGray
TypeForegroundColor                    : Gray
NumberForegroundColor                  : White
MemberForegroundColor                  : White
DefaultTokenBackgroundColor            : DarkMagenta
CommentBackgroundColor                 : DarkMagenta
KeywordBackgroundColor                 : DarkMagenta
StringBackgroundColor                  : DarkMagenta
OperatorBackgroundColor                : DarkMagenta
VariableBackgroundColor                : DarkMagenta
CommandBackgroundColor                 : DarkMagenta
ParameterBackgroundColor               : DarkMagenta
TypeBackgroundColor                    : DarkMagenta
NumberBackgroundColor                  : DarkMagenta
MemberBackgroundColor                  : DarkMagenta
EmphasisForegroundColor                : Cyan
EmphasisBackgroundColor                : DarkMagenta
ErrorForegroundColor                   : Red
ErrorBackgroundColor                   : DarkMagenta
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run PowerShell in [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/), you can change the actual RGB values of the colors.

Some screenshots from the ConEmu web site:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try `concfg` for getting preset themes/settings.
https://github.com/lukesampson/concfg/blob/master/README.md

Comment: You can try or this will do that for sure? Answers should be verified to work as expected before posting as an answer.